# Watch FTP folder via node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need to watch ftp folder for files create/update/remove events.
But I can't find any suitable solution to do this using node.js.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: You can't use node to "watch" a remote folder over FTP protocol. It doesn't work like that. You can watch a folder that's on the same machine as node.

Comment: Thank you. Wish you great day.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need get recursive listing of remote ftp directory and save it (look at https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp and https://github.com/evanplaice/node-ftpsync)
2. Set timeout to get new recursive listing
3. Compare new and old listing (look at https://github.com/andreyvit/json-diff) and call handlers to the corresponding events
4. Overwrite old listing with new
5. Return to step two

Comment: Thank you. I'll do this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sftp-watcher modules. which will reduce your time.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sftp-watcher